# Finding social sports clubs in Berlin

Tags: online-resources, germany, berlin, activities, long-term

How to find weekly sessions of badminton or basketball in Berlin?

- The only place I have found a few listings is on http://berlin.meetup.com/ but there are not many there.
- Does it really require walking into schools and sport halls to ask if they have any open non-league groups active there, or are there some Germany or Berlin specific web listings out there?

Comment: For questions around long-term stays, you might be better off on Expats

Comment: @pnuts Thanks, but when I looked at them, they seemed to be mainly to hire a court yourself rather than join a social club ... (or false positives for tennis etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I lived in Berlin a few years ago, I used to play basketball with the sport club of the Technical University https://www.tu-sport.de/index.php?id=31. It is open to people outside the university, too, and the costs are very low. Be sure to book in advance when the new semester starts/ends, because some activities tend to become booked out quickly. The gym for basketball (but I've seen people play Badminton there as well) is in West Berlin just outside the ring (S Messe Süd).